# Is there any collection.findById equivalent SQL query statement

Tags: sql, node.js, database, mongodb, oracle

```
Collection.findById(new ObjectId(userId));
```

// equivalent sql query for findById()

Answer (score 0):

select * from Collection where userName = 'username' limit 1